# WebDAV files opening in readonly mode in office 2013

Tags: webdav

WebDAV .docx files are opening in read-only mode in office 2013. Issue is with chrome + office 2013 combination. Everything working fine in chrome + office 2010 combination.

There are no issue in IE + Office 2010/2013. Below are the WebDAV method request order in IE and Chrome.

**Chrome**
options
get
post
post
post
post
head
propfind
get
head
post
post

**IE**
options
get
post
post
post
post
head
options
lock
get
propfind
head
post
post
unlock